# Using Python-pptx, what conditions could a PowerPoint have that give KeyError?

Tags: python-3.x, python-pptx

I have a PowerPoint that I would like to open, amend, and save as a different filename. However, I'm getting a KeyError.

I tried this code with a blank PowerPoint presentation and it works perfectly. However, when I use the code to ope an existing PowerPoint presentation and try to run the same code, I get a KeyError.

KeyError: "There is no item named 'ppt/slides/NULL' in the archive"

```
#Replace Source Text

import re
#s = "string. With. Punctuation?"
#s = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',s)

search_str = '{{{FILTER}}}'
repl_str = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',(str(list(dashboard_filter2.values()))))
ppt = Presentation('HispPres1.pptx')

for slide in ppt.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if shape.has_text_frame:
            shape.text = shape.text.replace(search_str, repl_str)
ppt.save('HispPresSourceUpdate.pptx')
```

I expect to have the existing PowerPoint amended by finding all the instances of {{{FILTER}}} and replacing it with the value listed. However, it looks like there's a problem using my existing PowerPoint presentation. I don't have this issue with a blank presentation.

So, I'm wondering what would cause an existing PowerPoint presentation to raise an error??? I plan on making several "templates" to start with and really need to know if there are any hardfast rules to adhere to.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-41deffabe2f9> in <module>()
      7 search_str = '{{{FILTER}}}'
      8 repl_str = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',(str(list(dashboard_filter2.values()))))
----> 9 ppt = Presentation('HispPres1.pptx')
     10 
     11 for slide in ppt.slides:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\api.py in Presentation(pptx)
     28         pptx = _default_pptx_path()
     29 
---> 30     presentation_part = Package.open(pptx).main_document_part
     31 
     32     if not _is_pptx_package(presentation_part):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\package.py in open(cls, pkg_file)
    120         *pkg_file*.
    121         """
--> 122         pkg_reader = PackageReader.from_file(pkg_file)
    123         package = cls()
    124         Unmarshaller.unmarshal(pkg_reader, package, PartFactory)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\pkgreader.py in from_file(pkg_file)
     34         pkg_srels = PackageReader._srels_for(phys_reader, PACKAGE_URI)
     35         sparts = PackageReader._load_serialized_parts(
---> 36             phys_reader, pkg_srels, content_types
     37         )
     38         phys_reader.close()

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\pkgreader.py in _load_serialized_parts(phys_reader, pkg_srels, content_types)
     67         sparts = []
     68         part_walker = PackageReader._walk_phys_parts(phys_reader, pkg_srels)
---> 69         for partname, blob, srels in part_walker:
     70             content_type = content_types[partname]
     71             spart = _SerializedPart(partname, content_type, blob, srels)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\pkgreader.py in _walk_phys_parts(phys_reader, srels, visited_partnames)
    102             yield (partname, blob, part_srels)
    103             for partname, blob, srels in PackageReader._walk_phys_parts(
--> 104                     phys_reader, part_srels, visited_partnames):
    105                 yield (partname, blob, srels)
    106 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\pkgreader.py in _walk_phys_parts(phys_reader, srels, visited_partnames)
    102             yield (partname, blob, part_srels)
    103             for partname, blob, srels in PackageReader._walk_phys_parts(
--> 104                     phys_reader, part_srels, visited_partnames):
    105                 yield (partname, blob, srels)
    106 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\pkgreader.py in _walk_phys_parts(phys_reader, srels, visited_partnames)
     99             visited_partnames.append(partname)
    100             part_srels = PackageReader._srels_for(phys_reader, partname)
--> 101             blob = phys_reader.blob_for(partname)
    102             yield (partname, blob, part_srels)
    103             for partname, blob, srels in PackageReader._walk_phys_parts(

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pptx\opc\phys_pkg.py in blob_for(self, pack_uri)
    107         matching member is present in zip archive.
    108         """
--> 109         return self._zipf.read(pack_uri.membername)
    110 
    111     def close(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in read(self, name, pwd)
   1312     def read(self, name, pwd=None):
   1313         """Return file bytes (as a string) for name."""
-> 1314         with self.open(name, "r", pwd) as fp:
   1315             return fp.read()
   1316 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in open(self, name, mode, pwd, force_zip64)
   1350         else:
   1351             # Get info object for name
-> 1352             zinfo = self.getinfo(name)
   1353 
   1354         if mode == 'w':

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in getinfo(self, name)
   1279         if info is None:
   1280             raise KeyError(
-> 1281                 'There is no item named %r in the archive' % name)
   1282 
   1283         return info

KeyError: "There is no item named 'ppt/slides/NULL' in the archive"
```

Comment: Can you please include the full stack trace you get for the KeyError?

Comment: Sure. Sorry about that. I just updated the question to include the full KeyError.

Comment: Hard to tell without the full stack trace, but for some reason it thinks you are trying to look for a slide named `NULL` which seems incorrect. The full stack trace would include the longer error that shows where in the code the error was thrown. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: oh ok. Does this get me the full stack trace? `import traceback
traceback.print_stack()`

Comment: I'd expect it to print a long stack trace when your program fails, something like one of these: https://www.google.com/search?q=python+traceback&tbm=isch. Where are you running this code?

Comment: Apologies. I didn't know what that was called. I edited the question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is a bit of a thorny problem. The spec doesn't provide for a "broken" relationship (one that refers to a package-part that doesn't exist), but at least one library (Java-based if I recall correctly) does not clean up relationships properly in some cases, perhaps a slide delete operation in this case.

The gist of the explanation is this:

- A PPTX file is an Open Packaging Convention (OPC) package. DOCX and XLSX files are other examples of OPC packages.
- An OPC package is a Zip archive of multiple *parts* (official term, perhaps *package-part* more precisely). Each part is essentially a file, so something like `slide1.xml`, and they are arranged in a "directory structure".
- One part can be related to other parts. For example, a presentation part (`presentation.xml`) is related to each of its slide parts. These relationships are stored in a file like `presentation.xml.rels`. The relationship is keyed with a string like `"rId3"` and identifies the related part by its path in the package.
- One part *refers* to another using the key in its XML (e.g. `<p:sldId r:id="rId3"/>`). The target part is "looked-up" in the .rels file to find its path and get to it that way.
- The `KeyError` you're getting means that the .rels file has a `<Relationship>` element referring to the part `ppt/slides/NULL` (instead of something like `ppt/slides/slide3.xml`). Since there is no such part in the package, the lookup fails.

If you open the "template" file in PowerPoint and save it, I think it will repair itself. You might need to rearrange a slide and move it back to jostle that part of the code.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to patch the package by hand, removing any broken references and relationships. `opc-diag` can be handy for that.

Comment: All of the relationship elements seem to follow this pattern `<Relationship Id="x" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/slide" Target="slides/slide1.xml"/>\n`. I'm not seeing any missing names. Is there a problem with this element example?

Answer (score 1):

You can clean the PPTX from the dangling relations through:

File -> Info -> Check for Issues -> Inspect Document.

Clean up, save, replay python script.

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks Scanny for the help. You're exactly right. The lookup was looking for ppt/slides/slide#.xml and it wasn't finding a relationship for it. The reason is because the relationships are coded as just slides/slide#.xml (without ppt/). I did get into the opc-diag to see what I could do there, but I found an easy fix.

My previous code had a line that said `for slide in ppt.slides:` and this was the error: `KeyError: "There is no item named 'ppt/slides/NULL' in the archive"`. When browsed the PresentationML using opc-diag, I found that the relationship was set up like this: `<Relationship Id="x" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/slide" Target="slides/slide1.xml"/>\n`. The relationship does not include `ppt`.

So, to get rid of that lookup and have it match the way PowerPoint stores the slide relationships, I changed these lines:

`ppt = Presentation('HispPres1.pptx')
for slide in ppt.slides:`

to this

`ppt = Presentation('HispPres1.pptx')
slides = ppt.slides
for slide in slides:`

Comment: Hmm, well I'm glad you got it working, but I don't think your analysis of why is quite correct. the `Target="slides/slide1.xml"` reference is a _relative_ path, and I expect the .rels part it appears in is already in the `/ppt/` "directory". Also, your code change doesn't change things; both `slides` and `ppt.slides` refer to the `Slides` object for the presentation (that structure of calls is not related to actual location in the package). Anyway, glad it started working, I just don't think it for the reasons you thought :)

Comment: You're 100% right. For some reason it worked initially, but I couldn't replicate it. I had a company template behind the one that wasn't working. When I remove the company template (design master slide template scheme), it works. It works when I just use the basic default PowerPoint template.